# Java - onlineUsers() method that returns an ArrayList of all Users that are currently online?

Tags: java

I created a class called VideoExchangeCenter which represents the company website that users log in and out of in order to download videos. The class contains the attribute: users - an ArrayList of all registered Users (which may be either logged on or not logged on).

Additionally, I am required to create an onlineUsers() method that returns an ArrayList of all Users that are currently online. This method essentially creates and returns a new ArrayList each time it is called.

I'm struggling to figure out some way to determine if a specific user is online or not. I tried looking up similar problems, but most of the results I found were too complex for my programming level or were either unrelated to my problem. I would really appreciate some help or a push in the right direction.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class VideoExchangeCenter {
  ArrayList<User> users;      

  public VideoExchangeCenter()  {
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
  }
  public onlineUsers(){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically *you* have to define what "being online" means.

Obviously, users that are currently up/downloading content are online. Obviously, users that logged in, but later logged out are offline. Users that are currently logged in but didn't do anything for X hours, hmm, what about them?

So, the point is: there are multiple approaches to go about this. When users need to login to use your service, the server can keep track of that information. You can also store time stamps each time a user interacts with a system, and assume "when a user is inactive for 1 hour, he is considered offline".

So, in the real world, such a service has plenty of ways to determine who is "currently online", some being heuristics. What you do in your homework assignment depends on the broader context of it.